# System design - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on the architecture for a project that includes a Android and iOS apps and a web interface with a subset of the mobile apps functionalities. The project is basically a e-commerce solution. In all three interfaces I'm using Google Analytics to track some information. However I'm having an internal discussion about the extent of the information I should send to GA. What should I store in GA and what should I store in my own server?

Let me give you some examples.

- Session tracking is clearly something that belong to GA.
- ProductDetailViews. Sounds like something that should go into GA, specially considering the enhanced e-commerce module.
- Shared item. When a user shares some content over a social network, should I store that information on GA or in my own server? I'm inclined to GA but it becomes more ambiguos.

Do you see my point? Can someone share a general rule or recommendation on what should be saved in GA and what should be saved on the projects own server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those examples I would generally send all the hits to Google Analytics.  Here are a few reasons:

- **Preventing data silos.**  You want all of your data in one place and Google provides you with a database reachable via the API where you can keep all your data organised in one place.  This is important when you are considering measuring performance, as you want to avoid duplication of conversions or traffic hits
- **Useage of Google Analytics advanced segments.** With all your data in GA, you will be able to create advanced segments for analysis.  But the real power is if you are using AdWords or retargeting, as you can send those Advanced Segments to AdWords, and target those users around the web with your custom data
- **Single point of reference for users** All analytics are inaccurate, but you want to make sure they are inaccurate to the same degree.  Using GA keeps all your data on the same playing field
- **Usability and Freedom of information** Its easier to serve up your data to users within the GA interface as people are more likely to know how to navigate that than your database.  You can also use the GA API to pull out any data you need to push into other visualisation tools.
- **User session merging** With your data and userID tracking in GA, you may be able to track users as they arrive via mobile to desktop and back again, over multiple sessions.

What you need to avoid putting in to Google Analytics is personal info such as names, email address etc.  There are against the TOS.  But you can capture a unique userID, and match that outside of the tool later.